# Regex: limit both the whole match AND character classes within

Tags: regex

Is it possible with regex to allow a match to have a maximum number of characters, divided between different character classes?

I need to match a number of up to 4 digits in total, with or without decimal digits. So these should all match the regex:

```
123
1234
12.34
123.4
```

But these should not:

```
12345
12.345
```

In concept, something like this should work, except it doesn't:

```
([0-9]{0,4}([.]?[0-9]{0,4})){0,4}
```

Comment: Do you want to match when the whole input is the number, or are the numbers within a larger input?

Comment: Are `12.` and `.12` valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *look ahead* to assert there's at most 1 dot:

```
^(?!([^.]\.){2})(?!\d{5})[\d.]{3,5}$
```

- `(?!([^.]\.){2})` means "looking ahead anywhere, there aren't 2 dots
- `(?!\d{5})` means "looking ahead, there aren't 5 straight digits"
- `[\d.]{3,5}` means "3-5 of digits and dots"

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/B9vWQrFstU).

---

To restrict decimal digits to maximum 2, add a `(?!.*\.\\d{3,}$)` which is a negative look ahead for "dot then 3+ digits at the end", ie:

```
^(?!([^.]\.){2})(?!\d{5})(?!.*\.\\d{3,}$)[\d.]{3,5}$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/k7ubBe90jc).

Comment: @Vallentin you're not testing my regex: You've left off the `^` and `$`

Comment: You're assuming there's 1 number per line. That's not how OP presented the question however.

Comment: @Vallentin that's a matter of opinion - let's ask OP

Comment: Nice solution, very generic. Is there a way to limit the number of allowed decimal digits to, for example, 2?

Comment: @MichielMeulendijk Yes. See edited answer and extra demo link for restricting decimal places to 2.

Comment: Not sure if it is mandatory, but this is not matching numbers less than 3 digit long.

Comment: @toto matching only lengths 3 to 5 is intentional because all of OP's examples were such.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but you can do it like this:

```
(\d{1,4}|\d{0,3}\.\d|\d{0,2}\.\d{0,2}|\d\.\d{0,3})
```

Just make sure that you have some boundary control character around it.

Say like this:

```
(?:^|[^\d.])(\d{1,4}|\d{0,3}\.\d|\d{0,2}\.\d{0,2}|\d\.\d{0,3})(?:$|[^\d.])
```

You can [see here](https://regex101.com/r/O7RYm3/2) that it works as intended.

I would however advice to use another tool for this specific case.

Comment: The decimals need to be optional, don't they?

Comment: @KennethK They are `\d{0,4}` matches `1234`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Sorry  : \

Answer (score 1):

The following *regex* should do it ...

```
\b(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1}\.\d{1,3}|(?<!\.)\d{1,4}(?!\.))\b
```

see **[*regex demo / explanation*](https://regex101.com/r/zuWXd2/3)**

Answer (score 1):

If your regex flavor accept it, you could use lookahead like:

*Edit: allow max 2 decimal*

```
^(?:\d{1,4}|(?=.{1,5}$)\d+\.\d{1,2})$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of string
  (?:           : start non capture group
    \d{1,4}     : 1 up to 4 digit
    |           : OR
    (?=         : lookahead
      .{1,5}$   : 1 up to 5 character (it could be .{3,5} if at least 1 digit is mandatory on each side of the dot)
    )           : end lookahead
    \d+         : 1 or more digits, integer part
    \.          : dot
    \d{1,2}     : 1 or 2 digits, decimal part
  )             : end group
$               : end of string
```

```js
var test = [
123,
1234,
12.34,
123.4,
12345,
12.345,
1.234
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^(?:\d{1,4}|(?=.{1,5}$)\d+\.\d{1,2})$/.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: @MichielMeulendijk: Be aware that accepted answer doesn't match number less than 3 digit long, ie. `1` or `45`